# SQL Server Profiler. Duration: 18446744073709547 microseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Does anyone knows why this weird value of query execution could be displayed in SQL Server Perfomance profiler.
[image]

Comment: This is more of a [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) question, really...

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Use formatted text instead of images, please!

Comment: I knew this looked familiar. Apparently this topic is [fashionable at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53413880/4137916).

Comment: `2^64 / 1000 = 18446744073709551.616`. This is so close to the magic number featured here that I doubt it's a coincidence. It looks like some sort of funky overflow condition (interpreting a signed value as unsigned somewhere); whether it's a bug in Profiler or the engine itself is another matter.